# ERROR: Expression Must have a pointer to class C++

Tags: c++, struct

Hi I faced this problem and I research and there should not be a problem with my code. So I not sure why this is happening, Basically I have this:

```
typedef struct {

Edge *next;
Edge *twin;

 } Edge;
```

Then I have a vector that stores this struct

```
std::vector<Edge*> EdgeList;
```

However when I try to access the member of this edge I face the above error.

```
Edge *e1
e1->next = EdgeList[index]->next->twin;
```

I am able access only up to one degree as in if I write my code in this way;

```
Edge *e1, *e2;
e2 = EdgeList[index]->next;
e1->next = e2->twin;
```

The error disappear. Note I have made sure that all the pointers are not NULL. I would like to ask why is it so? If I would to access several degrees, I cannot be declaring one variable at a time for each degree. Can someone help?

Comment: Have you read about `new`?

Comment: You are attempting to use uninitialized pointers. e1 should be declared Edge e1; and accessed using e1.next, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you've created an anonymous struct and a variable of that (anonymous) type called Edge, instead of creating a type called Edge.

Change the struct declaration to:

```
struct Edge
{
    Edge *next;
    Edge *twin;
};
```

P.S: You don't need to use typedef in C++.

P.P.S: I don't know what your use case is, but you should probably store the struct directly into the vector instead of pointers to them.